# R labelled values functions to sort labels or drop unused labels do nothing. Why?

Tags: r, labelled

My question relates to

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)
library(sjlabelled)
```

What I am trying to do is clean up some labelled data from SPSS prior to conversion for factors so I can run regressions that make sense. This means getting rid of those small catch-all categories which dont really help much.

The steps are
Step One ) replacing NA with 0 and labelling it "missing"
Step Two ) finding the value of "Other", finding all instances and recoding them to zero
Step Three) sorting all the labels by value and dropping "Other" as unused.

```
tdf2 <- as.data.frame(haven::read_sav(file.choose())
test2 <- tdf2[, 'AgeGender']
```

Thats how I actually get the data that for reproducability should look like

```
set.seed(123)
test2 <- sample(1:15, size = 3000, replace = TRUE)
add_labels(test2, labels = c("female 18-24" = 1, "female 25-34" =2, etc see below up to 15)
changetoNA <- which(test2 %in% sample(test2, 15))
test2[changetoNA] <- NA
```

```
# STEP ONE
test2[is.na(test2)] <- 0
val_label(test2,0) <- "missing"
# STEP TWO
z <- stack(attr(test2,"labels")  # create a df of labels and values
y <- which(z == "Other", arr.ind = TRUE)[1] # look up the row index of the subset of Other
test2[test2 == y] <- 0  # change the values of that row index to zero
attributes(test2)$class  # now take a look at the class
z # and the table z
```

$class
haven_labelled vctrs-vctr double

1 female 18-24
2 female 25-34
3 female 35-44
4 female 45-54
5 female 55-64
6 female 65-74
7 female 75+
8 male 18-24
9 male 25-34
10 male 35-44
11 male 45-54
12 male 55-64
13 male 65-74
14 male 75+
15 Other
0 missing

So what I want to do is sort the value labels so that missing takes its rightful place as the first in the list and drop "other" altogether.

```
# STEP THREE
drop_unused_value_labels(test2)
sort_val_labels(test2, according_to = "values")
```

does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I feel sooo dumb!

```
test2 <- drop_unused_value_labels(test2)
test2 <- sort_val_labels(test2, according_to = "values")
```

works fine.

(sigh)